# Customizing view in list with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE

Tags: android

I'm using a list with choice mode set to ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE. Can I use my own layout instead of simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml? Which standard views has it to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Can I use my own layout instead of simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml?
```

Yes, you can use your own layout. This layout is used to fill rows of `ListView`.

```
Which standard views has it to include?
```

You can use any layout, you want.
e.g. Following is example of one of such layout which I used in one of my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="23dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon1"
            android:layout_width="22px" android:paddingLeft="2px"
            android:paddingRight="2px" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon2" android:layout_width="22px"
            android:paddingLeft="2px" android:paddingRight="2px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/icon2" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="13sp" android:text="default" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If you need to use check boxes then you can use `CheckedTextView` as used in `simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml`

Hope this helps !!